# How can I display more then one video in an HTML5 page?

Tags: javascript, html, video

I need to change the location of an HTML5 video tag in a web page. By changing the location I mean passing the tag  to another place in the DOM tree.

If I use the JQuery clone function like

> $("#first").clone().appendTo("#second");

The video will start from the beggining and it will have to load again.

Is it possible to change the location of a media element like the video element to another part of the tree without having to load the video or audio again? Or at least, is it possible to have more then one player displaying the same video at the same time in a page?

Comment: Why are you cloning via javascript? Just add more `<video>` elements in your HTML.

Comment: Yes. I can do that. But I wanted to know if it is possible to have two players displaying the same video with the same meta information.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Give it a shot at http://jsfiddle.net/